# SphinxSearch round value

Tags: sphinx

need to round value from same example:

```
SELECT INTEGER(100-INTEGER(15692)*100/INTEGER(19590));
```

How can I do it on SphinxSearch

Is there any way to round value in spinxSearch (instead of adding 0.5 and flooring)

P.S for that moment find only [creating custom functions](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinx-udfs)

Comment: The question is not clear. `INTEGER(100-INTEGER(15692)*100/INTEGER(19590))` works in Sphinx. You can also use `FLOOR()` and `CEIL()` for rounding down and up. There's no `ROUND()` for rounding to the closest integer.

Comment: @ManticoreSearch that`s actually was the question) is there any way to round value in spinxSearch (instead of adding 0.5 and flooring). Thank you

Comment: Surely you already know the solution? Use FLOOR (well can use CEIL too)

Comment: @barryhunter the solution was to rewrite the code to avoid using math operations by DB

Comment: ironcially, if sphinx/manticore was to implement a 'ROUND' function, it might well end up just being a wrapper around `FLOOR(x+0.5)` as it's probably an efficient way to implement it, at least for positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

So, there is no `ROUND` function in Sphinx.

My solution was to change app code, and do this thing on code side, instead of Sphinx.

Also, my variant with `FLOOR(x+0.5)` was approved in comments, use it if you need